# Limits in the amount of downloadable data with snscrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, social-networking, scrape

I’m facing an university project about NLP with Twitter data. I’d like to know if there are limitations about the amout of data that can be downloaded with snscrape library istead of official api